# Edit polygon - QGIS - remove a line or space in middle of merged polygon

Tags: qgis, merge, mapping

I am editing a map using QGIS. Here my steps

#### 1. Select multiple polygons

[image: Select multiple polygons for merging]

#### 2. Merge them into one new polygon

[image: Merged polygon with some line in middle]

**Question:** How can I remove those line (in blue circle) and one polygon fully cover the area without any lines or space in between? (this case it only a line but there could be chance that I want to fill some space in between)

Comment: A "quick and dirty" method is to simply use the node tool to select those unwanted vertices (draw a box around them) and then delete them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different possibilities for manually removing a hole. Easiest is probably solution 1:

1. Use the [Delete ring](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#delete-ring) icon and click on the gap to make it disappear:

[image]

---

Other possibilities:

2. Draw another polygon that covers the hole and merge again.
3. Activate vertex tool, mark and delete all vertices of the hole.

Answer (score 2):

Still another option is the use the tool [Delete holes](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#delete-holes): `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Delete holes`

Answer (score 1):

To automatically remove all interior rings, use QGIS expressions with the function [`exterior_ring()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#exterior-ring) that returns just the exterior ring (boundary), than convert this to a polygon. Like this, all interior rings are automatically deleted. Use this expression to get polygons without holes:

`make_polygon (exterior_ring ($geometry))`

Use this with either  [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) (visualization only) or [Geometry by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (for actual geometries). [See here for more details about both options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814).

*Initial polygon with hole (yellow) and polygon created with the expression, covering the hole (red lines):*
[image]